# How do I end a function that is using callbacks in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write some code that allow me to 'drag and drop' some lines over a figure so that I can obtain a particular coordinate: 'pt'. I am adapting some code from the internet that uses call backs, which is doing what I want it to do. However, I am unable to end the function or transfer the coordinate 'pt' to another function. I have attempted to use 'return', but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried to use 'while', but it caused Matlab to crash.

I am new to programming, so detailed suggestions would be appreciated.

```
function [pt] = movelines
global pt;   
f=figure;
aH=axes('Xlim',[0, 1],'YLim', [0 1]);
key=0;


H=line([0 1], [0.5 0.5], ...                                       %from [x1 x2] to [y1 y2]
    'color', 'yellow',...
    'linewidth', 3);

V=line([0.5 0.5], [0 1], ...                      %This line sets the length of the line. From [x1 x2] to [y1 y2]
    'color', 'red', ...
    'linewidth',3,...
    'ButtonDownFcn', @startDragFcn);


set(f, 'WindowButtonUpFcn',@stopDragFcn);

mov_cancel = uicontrol(f,'Style','pushbutton',...
                        'Position',[30,130,110,30],...
                        'String','(cancel)',...
                        'BusyAction','cancel',...
                        'TooltipString','BusyAction = cancel',...
                        'Callback',@funct_cancel);


function startDragFcn (gcbo,eventdata,handles)

    set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@draggingFcn)

    end

    function draggingFcn (gcbo,eventdata,handles)


        pt=get(aH,'CurrentPoint');

        set(V,'Xdata',pt(1)*[1 1]);
        set(H,'Ydata',pt(1,2)*[1 1])        
    end


    function stopDragFcn (gcbo,eventdata,handles)

        set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn','');        
    end


    function funct_cancel (gcbo,eventdata,handles)
         key=key+1
         return


    end

end
```

To use the code, click and hold the vertical line. The function is supposed to end when the cancel button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Matlab function `waitfor` to wait for a uicontrol object to close.  I've also added functionality to stop allowing the user to drag the lines around after you cancel.

```
function [pt] = movelines()
f=figure;
enabled = 1;
aH=axes('Xlim',[0, 1],'YLim', [0 1]);
key=0;

H=line([0 1], [0.5 0.5], ...  %from [x1 x2] to [y1 y2]
    'color', 'yellow',...
    'linewidth', 3);

V=line([0.5 0.5], [0 1], ...  %This line sets the length of the line. From [x1 x2] to [y1 y2]
    'color', 'red', ...
    'linewidth',3,...
    'ButtonDownFcn', @startDragFcn);

set(f, 'WindowButtonUpFcn',@stopDragFcn);

mov_cancel = uicontrol(f,'Style','pushbutton',...
                        'Position',[30,130,110,30],...
                        'String','(cancel)',...
                        'BusyAction','cancel',...
                        'TooltipString','BusyAction = cancel',...
                        'Callback',@funct_cancel);

function startDragFcn (gcbo,eventdata,handles)
    if enabled
        set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@draggingFcn)
    end
end

function draggingFcn (gcbo,eventdata,handles)
    pt=get(aH,'CurrentPoint');
    set(V,'Xdata',pt(1)*[1 1]);
    set(H,'Ydata',pt(1,2)*[1 1])        
end

function stopDragFcn (gcbo,eventdata,handles)
    set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn','');        
end

function funct_cancel (gcbo,eventdata,handles)
     key=key+1
     enabled=0;
     delete(mov_cancel);
end
waitfor(mov_cancel);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I assume there is a reason that you aren't using `ginput`. If you haven't considered it then you should, see: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html

So assuming you want to proceed with your current approach:

Your code at the moment seems to terminate fine, do you mean that you want to close the figure. If so you can do this using `delete(gcf)` within your callback function.

In terms of returning the current point you could declare `pt` as a global variable. You can then use it anywhere you want. Remember to declare a global variable at the beginning of each function you use it in.

```
function draggingFcn (gcbo,eventdata,handles)
        global  pt;
        pt=get(aH,'CurrentPoint');

        set(V,'Xdata',pt(1)*[1 1]);
        set(H,'Ydata',pt(1,2)*[1 1])
    end
```

Hope I've answered your questions there. If you can though I would seriously consider `ginput`